# Pointer to void in C preprocessor

Tags: c, gcc, goto, pointer-arithmetic

I read this source (https://github.com/lattera/glibc/blob/master/stdio-common/vfprintf.c) and find some interesting lines, which I do not fully understand:

```
#ifdef SHARED
/* 'int' is enough and it saves some space on 64 bit systems.  */
# define JUMP_TABLE_TYPE const int
# define JUMP_TABLE_BASE_LABEL do_form_unknown
# define REF(Name) &&do_##Name - &&JUMP_TABLE_BASE_LABEL
# define JUMP(ChExpr, table)                              \
  do                                      \
{                                     \
  int offset;                                 \
  void *ptr;                                  \
  spec = (ChExpr);                            \
  offset = NOT_IN_JUMP_RANGE (spec) ? REF (form_unknown)          \
    : table[CHAR_CLASS (spec)];                       \
  ptr = &&JUMP_TABLE_BASE_LABEL + offset;                 \
  goto *ptr;                                  \
}                                     \
  while (0)

 ...

#define STEP0_3_TABLE                                 \
/* Step 0: at the beginning.  */                          \
static JUMP_TABLE_TYPE step0_jumps[30] =                      \
{                                         \
  REF (form_unknown),                             \
  REF (flag_space),     /* for ' ' */                     \
  REF (flag_plus),      /* for '+' */                     \
  REF (flag_minus),     /* for '-' */                     \
  REF (flag_hash),      /* for '<hash>' */                \
  REF (flag_zero),      /* for '0' */                     \
  REF (flag_quote),     /* for '\'' */                    \
  REF (width_asterics), /* for '*' */                     \
  REF (width),      /* for '1'...'9' */               \
  REF (precision),      /* for '.' */                     \
  REF (mod_half),       /* for 'h' */                     \
  ...
```

I wrote simple example and understand that this line `&&do_##Name` cast `do_##Name` to pointer to void. But I don't understand how works pointer arithmetic in this case:  `#define REF(Name) &&do_##Name - &&JUMP_TABLE_BASE_LABEL` Can someone write simple explanation? Or write some link to Internet resource where I can read about this technique.

Comment: Proporcessor does not know anything about the C language and pointers

Comment: You might want to have a look at the preprocessed C code. With GCC you can do `cpp file.c` to see it.

Comment: Here gcc goto extension is used - this not very standard C

Comment: @P__J__ And pointer arithmetic on `void *`, another gcc extension.

Comment: @P__J__ I don't know about this. Thank you

Comment: @melpomene indeed. But it is gcc glibc :). Anyway this is  a very efficient gcc code but not the code I would recommend to learn from. It is written to be as efficient as possible. Come back to it when you get more experience

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presumably to be guaranteed to have liner complexity, the code is using a jump table made of labels used as values.

[Labels-as-values](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.2/gcc/Labels-as-Values.html) is a GNU C extension which allows you to use `&&` to take the address of a label. The address is typed `void *` and you can then use `goto *address;` to jump to it.

The little twist with the base label is that instead of storing absolute labels in the table, to code is storing offsets from a `do_uknown_form` label.

That saves space (the offset can be an 4 byte int instead of an 8 byte pointer) in the table and helps generated better code for shared libs (hence the `#ifdef SHARED`) as even a `static const` jump table of absolute labels would need to be patched when the code is loaded in a relocatable shared library, but the offsets remain the same so then the need for patching vanishes and the table can be stored in read-only memory.

The technique is described in the [How to Write Shared Libraries](http://www.cs.miami.edu/home/burt/learning/Csc521.091/docs/dsohowto.pdf) essay by Ulrich Drepper.